# "Verify live version" not available in Google Webmaster Tools

Tags: google-search-console, robots.txt

I was searching how to submit a robots.txt file using Google Webmaster Tools and I see no option of **Verify live version**, which is the forth step in submitting a robots.txt file to Google.

I went through the docs: [Submit your updated robots.txt to Google](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6078399?hl=en)

Can somebody tell me where I can find that option?

Comment: Note that the file has to be called `robots.txt`, not `robot.txt` (I have changed it in your question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the options have changed.

I think the 'Verify live version' is now the 'view uploaded version' option.

[image]

Follow the instructions, its pretty simple.  Press submit and you will get a successful message, then refresh to see the new robots.txt you uploaded.